# Matrix representation of multiplication of elements in Galois Field

Tags: matrices, finite-fields

I would appreciate it if you could please explain how in the following example the mod by f(x) results in the suggested answer (orange frame). Example at the top of page 3, https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/1090.pdf.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how the mod by f(x) results in the suggested answer (orange frame)

If $x^3+x+1=0$ in characteristic $2$, then $x^3=x+1$ and $x^4=x^2+x$.

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Thank you so much @j-w-tanner, greatly appreciate your help. I have been staring at this the whole day not being able to figure it out.